# How do I create functionality limitations for my SaaS app based on the pricing tier?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments, subscription

I've created an app with functionality-based pricing and integrated stripe but I'm struggling how to figure out how to incorporate limitations in capability based on the subscription tier.

**Pricing tiers**

1. Basic - 2 QR codes and 35 attendees
2. Scaled - 7 QR codes and 50 attendees
3. Enterprise - 10 QR codes and 500 attendees

What I'd like to do is have the users subscription validated as they're looking to create an event and 1) make sure they don't haven't exceeded the # of QR codes for their tier and 2) use the attendee count to create an array. I can figure out how to structure the logic I just need help integrating the pricing tier data.

**Event creation function**

```
module.exports.showActivations = async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
    const qr = await Qr.find({ user: user._id }).populate('event');

    const qrAgg = await Qr.aggregate([
        {
            $match: { user: user._id }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'events',
                localField: 'event',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'event'
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: '$event'
        },
        {
            $sort: { 'event.event_start': -1 }
        }
    ]);
    const activeEvents = await Event.find({ user: user.id, event_end: { $gte: Date.now() } }).populate('qr');
    
    // for loop to create QR codes for user when they visit the page for the first time
    
    if (qr.length < 1 && <where I'd like to pass in the QR count based on tier>) {
        for (let i = qr.length; i < 6; i++) {
            const url = `https://${req.headers.host}/users/${user.id}/qr-` + (1 + i);
            const qrGenerator = await QRCode.toDataURL(url);
            const name = "qr-" + (1 + i);
            const qr = new Qr({
                user: user._id,
                url: url,
                qrcode: qrGenerator,
                name: name,
            });
            await qr.save();
        }
        res.render('users/activations', { activeEvents, qr, qrAgg });

    } else {
        res.render('users/activations', { activeEvents, qr, qrAgg });
    }
};
```

**Price id mapping attempt**

```
const priceToQrMappings = {
    price_id1: 2,
    price_id2: 7,
    price_id3: 10
   };
```

How do I pass in the appropriate # of QR codes to the for loop function based on user price tier?

Answer (score 0):

You should update your code to implement a simple mapping of the Price ID -> the number of QR codes allowed for that price, and then assuming you know which Stripe Price ID your customer is subscribed to by the time you get to the QR code generation for loop, you can use that mapping to look up how many QR codes to generate.

Comment: Hi @karbi - thanks for the comment, I think I'm following your logic. I added an attempted price id mapping to the question... just want to confirm, is this what you mean around implementing the mapping?